# Api сайта госуслуг

Tags: api, поиск-api

Есть ли api сайта госуслуг? В гугле ничего талкового не нашел. Т.е. нужна авторизация через госуслуги и выполнение действий как на самом сайте.

Comment: ты про какие госуслуги? gosuslugi.ru или какие-то другие? А то их так-то много

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, gosuslugi.ru

Answer (score 1):

Вот посмотрите тут, гуглом нарыл: http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/portal/

Comment: Уже заходил. Не совсем понятно что к чему

Comment: ну тут куча сервисов для получения нужной информации: http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/portal/data_types.jsp#!/FOIV

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется сделать вход на сайт через госуслуги, как аналог авторизации через соц сети.
Тогда вам нужна вот эта инструкция https://partners.gosuslugi.ru/catalog/esia